# MySQL Одновременное заполнение таблиц со связью М:М

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Имеется база данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица ingredient связана с таблицами recipe, product и cooking_method связью М:М, но т.к. физически такая связь нереализуема, то между этими таблицами вставлены промежуточные таблицы с ключевыми полями от соответствующих таблиц и связью М:1. Возникла трудность - при добавлении записи в таблицу ingredient наверное нужно чтобы промежуточные таблицы заполнялись автоматически. Например я добавляю ингредиент, выбираю к какому рецепту он относится и ввожу его массу/количество (поле amount в таблице r_i), в зависимости от единицы измерения (таблица unit), и в промежуточной таблице r_i должна появиться запись с id_recipe, id_ingredient и amount. Как это реализовать?

Comment: По моему скромному мнению, Вы задачу видите немного не так. Ингредиент никак не зависит от рецепта, таблица ингредиентов пополняется сама по себе. При составлении рецепта уже имеющиеся ингредиенты и их количества заносятся в таблицу r_i, Тоже самое, что в классическом примере заказов. Products - ингредиенты, Orders - рецепты, состоящие из OrderLines - r_i, которые ссылаются на product_id и количество этого продукта.

Comment: @Sergey как должна заполняться таблица i_p, автоматически?

Comment: Создайте триггер на таблице в которой вы хотите отслеживать изменения. В триггере задайте условия по которым вы хотите обновлять промежуточные таблицы.

Comment: Никак она автоматически не заполняется. Да и не возможно это. Как будет например заполняться количество, которое в r_i, к примеру? Силою мысли поварёнка что ли планируете воспользоваться? Сколько капнуть майонеза? Только подумал, и не касаясь клавиш компьютера, 100г капнуло в r_i.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В MySQL существует понятие триггера. Его можно объявить следующим образом

```
CREATE TABLE account (acct_num INT, amount DECIMAL(10,2));

CREATE TRIGGER trig_name BEFORE INSERT ON account
     FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + NEW.amount;

SET @sum = 0;
INSERT INTO account VALUES(137,14.98),(141,1937.50),(97,-100.00);
SELECT @sum AS 'Total amount inserted';
```

ключевое слово `NEW` примет текущее значение в котором будет лежать данная таблица.

В вашем случае я думаю можно попробовать следующим образом.

Если записывать сперва в таблицу `recipe` то можно ее `id` запомнить в какую нибудь переменную,например `@recipe_id`.

Потом при записи в `ingredient`, сработает триггер и запишет оба результата в `pivote` (связывающую - `r_i`) таблицу.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_name BEFORE INSERT ON ingredient
     FOR EACH ROW (INSERT INTO r_i(id_recipe,id_ingredient) VALUES(@recipe_id,NEW.id));
```

Логика на мой взгляд верна для вашего решения. Главное правильно написать SQL.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html
Ну а если не хотите так.то вам придётся познакомиться с MySQL процедурами,
ну или записывать параллельно и в третью таблицу.

Надеюсь помог, удачи.

Comment: Только откуда при этом в r_i появится amount?